# Удалить картинку с сайта после просмотра

Tags: html, изображения

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Нужно сделать на сайте следующую функцию: когда любой юзер заливает любую картинку он указывает время просмотра в секундах. Когда кто угодно просматривает эту картинку она полностью удаляется с сайта через выбранное время.

Так и не сообразил как сделать. Может кто из знающих подскажет? Это вообще возможно реализовать? Понимаю, что задача нестандартная и выглядит странновато.

Comment: Вопрос в том, чтобы удалить с сервера, или в браузере запросившего она тоже должна исчезнуть без возможности восстановить? Принципиально разные задачи.

Comment: да нужно удалить с сервера и в браузере пользователя она тоже должна закрыться без возможности восстановить

Comment: после всяких snap-чатов - очень типичная.

Comment: Вы принципиально не любите пользователей? И что, такая функциональность востребована в Интернет?

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, еще как, вчера только заливал для техподдержки скрин имейла.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1.` На сервере сохраняем картинку с именем, в котором зашито время жизни, а в папке - сутки той даты, когда заканчивается время жизни:

- `../path/to/storage/1404000000/1404054523_5cb138284d431abd6a053a56625ec088bfb88912.jpg`
- `../path/to/storage/1403049600/1403096760_7e240de74fb1ed08fa08d38063f6a6a91462a815.jpg`
- `../path/to/storage/1403049600/1403096760_f36b4825e5db2cf7dd2d2593b3f5c24c0311d8b2.jpg`

Имя составляется из времени в формате Unixtime, когда картинка должна сдохнуть и уникального хэша содержимого картинки в формате sha1 или sha2. В PHP хэш вычисляется функцией sha1_file("путь/к/файлу");

Для удобства удаления файлы складываются в директории, в которых указаны сутки этой даты

1403049600 = 2014-06-18 00:00:00 +0000

`2.` Выдача картинок выполняется через nginx с подключенным модулем на Perl, который проверяет метку времени в имени файла с текущей датой. Этот скрипт делает внутренний редирект (проксирование) на файл или выдаёт ошибки (404 = файл устарел).

Почему perl? Потому что nginx умеет его типа компилировать в момент загрузки конфига и он не жрёт память как PHP.

Пример скрипта обсуждается вот в этой ветке форума: http://searchengines.guru/archive/index.php/t-570254.html

Также при выдаче картинки нужно установить заголовки, предотвращающие хранение картинки в кэше браузера.

```
location /storage/ {
    expires -1; # картинка устареет сразу же - при обновлении страницы должен запросить опять с сервера
    add_header Cache-Control private; # не кэшировать в браузере
}
```

`3.` Крон-задача удаляет все папки с картинками, у которых дата в имени меньше текущих суток

`4.` На странице пользователя вшит javascript, который прячет картинку после некоторого количества секунд просмотра: http://jsfiddle.net/copist/tLd6N/

Также поверх картинки нужно поместить <div style="background: transparent;">, что предотвратит "Сохранить картинку как..." при отключенном javascript (если пользователь не умеет самостоятельно удалять такие слои)

Также на страницу надо "повестить" javascript, который запретит контекстное меню по правому клику мыши (если javascript не выключен)

```
 <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

База данных не используется, работает очень быстро и достаточно стабильно.

Comment: f5 и лицезреем чудо. Вопрос немного про другое.

Comment: >>> да нужно удалить с сервера и в браузере пользователя она тоже должна закрыться без возможности восстановить

Comment: Значительно расширил свой ответ

Comment: Юзер, не будь дурак, сможет достать картинку из кеша. (Технически неподкованные юзеры не считаются.)

Comment: @VladD я поправил свой ответ. Теперь не сможет - её там не будет

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev: окей, let's [game of walls and ladders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) begin! А как насчёт кэширующего прокси: <http://stackoverflow.com/q/5013477/276994>?

P.S.: В любом случае, +1 от меня.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с вывихом: **отдавать потоковое видео**.

Из картинки генерится 10-секундный видеофайл. По ссылке www.site.ru/xxx.jpg отдается веб страница содержащая плеер, который проиграет [RTMP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) (а лучше RTMPE) поток этого 10-секундного видео. Сервер же после окончания передачи любого видео, его стирает.

RTMPE поток сложно перехватить/сохранить, в кэше он не сохраняется.

Можно задействовать Amazon Web Services — их CloudFront [умеет раздавать RTMPE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowStreamingDistributionsWork.html).

Comment: Гугл на "rtmp capture plugin" выдаёт пол-миллиона ссылок, так что упорный юзер сможет обойти и это. Но ваш вариант, видимо, самый сложный для клиента.

Comment: @VladD, а чем rtmp отличается от любого другого видео на МОЕМ компе (не на сервере)?

Ставим любую программку для записи с экрана - и видео наше. Здесь даже не надо знать в каком формате отдается видео.

И вы хоть что делайте, хоть шифрованными перепутанными частями отдавайте в свой же плеер, который будет эти части вместе склеивать и отображать - мне будет без разницы.

С тем же принтскрином посложнее будет - скопировать, вставить, обрезать, сохранить. А тут - скачал, одну кнопочку нажал, другую - и все.

Так что это вариант самый сложный для разработчика (ну если дальше не извращаться ))))

Comment: Хотя если видео из статичной картинки, то и принтскрина достаточно, не надо видео захватывать. Другое дело - качество картинки, но больше чем оно отображается на экране вы при любом раскладе не сделаете (если не сохранять исходник картинки)

Comment: @BOPOH: Хм, вы правы. Принтскрин непобедим.

Comment: Вариант с переломом))

Пишем свой плагин для браузера, который (1) на время просмотра отключает всякое управление, чтобы не было принта, (2) грузит цпу, чтобы если и начали записывать видео раньше чем открыли страницу, то нифига не записали, (3) с бешенной скоростью вращает картинку, так, чтобы ее суть было видно, но при записи/фотографириовании с камеры/телефона и т.д. картинка была всегда повернута под разными углами и сильно искажена.

Или как вариант - изучить мозги человека и создать девайс, который позволит этим мозгам видеть картинку, но при этом другим способом ее увидеть будет нельзя

Comment: Можно еще вместо картинки писать "здесь находится картинка" и описать что на ней находится ))

Других способов предупредить скачивание картинки любым человеком, мало-мальски знакомого с компом, не вижу...

UPD: @VladD, ну можно нанять человека, который будет приходить домой к каждому, кто видит нашу картинку и ставить там нужные нам плагины) Даже если плагины ставить по каким-то причинам нельзя (например, консоль)) - сносим все и ставим то, что нам надо)

Но это все фантазии, а про реальность вы уже сказали: "Принтскрин непобедим"

Comment: @BOPOH: ... и заставляем пользователя инсталлировать нативный плагин? На линуксе, например?

Comment: Как вариант, я вижу решение с printscreen таким: 

    $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 44) {
            // запускаем swf'ку, которая обновит буфер.
        }
    });

Comment: @lampa может, `"keydown"` лучше? Хотя на SO [считают, что без толку](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130983/stop-user-from-using-print-scrn-printscreen-key-of-the-keyboard-for-any-we).

Comment: @sergiks а вот keydown не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим у нас есть список картинок и их "время жизни" в unix формате:

```
+-------------+------------+
| image1.jpeg | 1403096760 |
+-------------+------------+
| image2.jpeg | 1404054523 |
+-------------+------------+
| image3.jpeg | 1405423411 |
+-------------+------------+
| ......                   |
+-------------+------------+
```

Есть несколько вариантов удаления файлов: это либо добавить задачу в cron планировщик, либо запускать скрипт проверки жизни файлов при каждом действии пользователя. Покажу на примере второго:

Есть файл: `image.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['image']) && isset($image_list[$_GET['image']])) {
    if($image_list[$_GET['image']] < time()) {
        unset($_GET['image']);
        header('location: /404.html');
    }
    header('location: /images/' . $_GET['image']);
}
```

Comment: Раз картинки одноразовые — их уместно отдавать через скрипт, который после выдачи уничтожит файл. Сложность в том, как защитить картинку на стороне клиента - уничтожить, не дать сохранить, заскриншотить.

Про закон «хранить все файлы пользователя минимум 3 месяца» я молчу.

Comment: @sergiks мне кажется, закон этот обходится также, как и в случае с "электронными испарителями", тупо переводить в base64, чем не текст?) На клиенте никак, тот же printscreen, не стоит вообще заморачиваться, достаточно поверх прозрачный блок положить, от дураков хватит) А вот почему я сделал не через скрипт, а просто редиректом - мне кажется, так будет проще самому серверу.

Comment: Можно еще генерить expiring ссылки - которые перестают быть действительными через указанное время (проверяется веб сервером при выдаче).

Comment: expiring ссылки не подходят так как нужно чтобы картинка закрывалась и в браузере скажем через секунд 10 это и есть по сути защита от скрина и сохранения так как человек выложивший картинку потом дает на нее ссылку другому а он и не подозревает что у него всего скажем 10 секунд чтобы ее заскринить или сохранить

Comment: @lampa: printscreen! Вы победили.

Comment: @xexmakcumka: Ну это только после первого раза, на второй раз все будут умнее.

Comment: @xexmakcumka, если цель - не дать сохранить, то зачем вообще тогда показывать?

Не спорю, необходимость в этом может быть, но здесь тогда многое от целей зависит.

Если, например, дизайнер хочет показать работу заказчику и не хочет, чтобы его обманули забрав картинку, то можно же отдавать картинку с каким-нибудь водяным знаком. Такая картинка будет непригодна для коммерческого использования, но заказчик увидит работу.

Если же хочешь свое голое фото показать другу, но не хочешь чтобы его сохранили - ну так не фиг показывать) Тем более, что сохранить в том или ином виде все равно можно